# Pasar de HTTP a HTTPS exceptuando dos URL con .htaccess hecho en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, apache

Tengo una pagina hecha en laravel, ya tiene los peremisos SSL para que sea HTTPS.

Digamos que esta como `https://www.mipagina.com` pero quiero que las rutas `www.mipagina.com/dondeesta` y las carpetas que esten dentro de "`empresa`" `www.mipagina.com/high/empresa/latest/` sean siempre HTTP

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dondeesta [OR]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^/high/empresa/latest/
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)$ public/$1 [L]
```

ya intente varios ejemplos de ver varias preguntas similares pero ninguna me da el resultado que quiero

Answer (score 0):

Si esas rutas las tienes colocadas dentro del código la única solución es cambiarlas a mano utilizando la función del propio laravel:

```
// Comprueba si la página "foo" se ha cargado bajo el protocolo HTTPS
Route::get('foo', array('https', function()
{
    return 'Must be over HTTPS';
}));
```

Ahora bien, para forzar que la página se vea en https hay que utilizar en .htaccess lo siguiente:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mipagina.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: y como se podria hacer a mano en laravel?

Comment: Tal vez [este artículo](http://www.rafelsanso.com/forzar-urls-https-en-laravel/) te puede ayudar.

Comment: Estuve investigando y me aparece que los Filtros del articulo que me paso esas funciones estan obsoletas para Laravel 5.0+